# Implementing common fraction using TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interview-questions, nunit

Recently, during the interview, I was asked to implement basic arithmetic operations with common fractions using TDD. The task is fairly simple, but I was nervous so I did not do too well. :) Later on I decided to give it another try in more... comfortable environment. Here is what I came up with.

**Tests:**

```
[TestFixture]
class FractionTests
{
    [Test]
    public void NormalizationTest()
    {
        var fraction = new Fraction(24, 36).Normalize();
        Assert.That(fraction.Numerator, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(fraction.Denominator, Is.EqualTo(3));
    }

    [Test]
    public void EqualityTest()
    {
        Assert.That(new Fraction(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(1, 2)));
        Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(1, 2)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ComparisonTest()
    {
        Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(1, 2)), Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(9, 4)), Is.EqualTo(-1));
        Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(1, 5)), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void AdditionTestWithSameDenominators()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(1,5);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(7,5);
        var result = fraction1.Add(fraction2);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(8, 5)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void AdditionTestWithDifferentDenominators()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(1, 25);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(6, 15);
        var result = fraction1.Add(fraction2);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(33, 75)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void SubtractionTestWithSameDenominators()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(1, 5);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(7, 5);
        var result = fraction1.Subtract(fraction2);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(-6, 5)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void SubtractionTestWithDifferentDenominators()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(1, 25);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(6, 15);
        var result = fraction2.Subtract(fraction1);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(27, 75)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void MultiplicationTest()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(2, 3);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(3, 5);
        var result = fraction1.Multiply(fraction2);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(6, 15)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void DivisionTest()
    {
        var fraction1 = new Fraction(2, 3);
        var fraction2 = new Fraction(3, 5);
        var result = fraction2.Divide(fraction1);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(9, 10)));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestZeroHandling()
    {
        var fraction = new Fraction(2,3);
        var zero = new Fraction(0, 29);

        Assert.That(fraction.Add(zero), Is.EqualTo(fraction));
        Assert.That(fraction.Subtract(zero), Is.EqualTo(fraction));
        Assert.That(fraction.Multiply(zero), Is.EqualTo(zero));
        Assert.That(() => fraction.Divide(zero), Throws.TypeOf<DivideByZeroException>());
    }
}
```

I am uncertain, if those tests are good enough. I am also fairly new to TDD, so any advice is welcome.

**Fraction class:**

```
public class Fraction : IEquatable<Fraction>, IComparable<Fraction>
{
    public Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1)
    {
        if (denominator < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("denominator", "Denominator should be greater than 0");

        Numerator = numerator;
        Denominator = denominator;
    }

    public int Numerator { get; private set; }
    public int Denominator { get; private set; }

    public Fraction Add(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        Fraction result;
        if (other.Denominator == Denominator)
        {
            result = new Fraction(Numerator + other.Numerator, Denominator);
        }
        else
        {
            var commonDenominator = Denominator*other.Denominator;
            var numerator = Denominator*other.Numerator + other.Denominator*Numerator;
            result = new Fraction(numerator, commonDenominator);
        }
        return result.Normalize();
    }

    public Fraction Subtract(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        return Add(new Fraction(-other.Numerator, other.Denominator));
    }

    public Fraction Multiply(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        return new Fraction(Numerator * other.Numerator, Denominator * other.Denominator).Normalize();
    }

    public Fraction Divide(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        if (other.Numerator == 0) throw new DivideByZeroException();
        return Multiply(new Fraction(other.Denominator, other.Numerator));
    }

    public Fraction Normalize()
    {
        var commonDivisor = FindCommonDivisor(Math.Abs(Numerator), Math.Abs(Denominator));
        return new Fraction(Numerator / commonDivisor, Denominator / commonDivisor);
    }

    public bool Equals(Fraction other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        var first = Normalize();
        var second = other.Normalize();
        return first.Numerator == second.Numerator && first.Denominator == second.Denominator;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Fraction);
    }

    public  override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var normalized = Normalize();
            return (normalized.Numerator * 397) ^ normalized.Denominator;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Fraction other)
    {
        return ToDouble().CompareTo(other.ToDouble());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/{1}", Numerator, Denominator);
    }

    public double ToDouble()
    {
        return (double)Numerator/Denominator;
    }

    private static int FindCommonDivisor(int first, int second)
    {
        if (second == 0)
        {
            return first;
        }
        var mod = first % second;
        return FindCommonDivisor(second, mod);
    }
}
```

Anything to improve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. A denominator can be negative!

   \$\dfrac{1}{-2} = \dfrac{-1}{2}\$

You should check that the denominator isn't zero, because *that*'s bad.

2. You could use operator overriding!

   ```
   public static Fraction operator +(Fraction fraction)
   {
       return this.Add(fraction);
   }
   ```

   You can do the same for *all* operators you have method for at the moment. (It's not an obligation, it's just cool :p)

Now, the tests:

```
[Test]
public void NormalizationTest()
{
    var fraction = new Fraction(24, 36).Normalize();
    Assert.That(fraction.Numerator, Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(fraction.Denominator, Is.EqualTo(3));
}
```

What's the purpose of your test? You normalize a `Fraction`, then you check if it's equal to `2/3`. How does this translates into code?

```
[Test]
public void NormalizationTest()
{
    var expected = new Fraction(2,3);
    var actual = new Fraction(24, 36).Normalize();

    Assert.That(expected, Is.EqualTo(actual));
}
```

See what I did there? Now, I know what's the expected result, I know what's the tested unit (`actual`), and I see clearly that I'm testing for equality, not that "members are equal one to each another". That seems like the same thing, but it's not!

```
[Test]
public void EqualityTest()
{
    Assert.That(new Fraction(1, 2), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(1, 2)));
    Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(1, 2)));
}
```

This method tests two things. The equality, and... something else, the normalization I suppose? Your test should test one thing, **one**. So test the equality, that's all!

What I meant is that you shouldn't test both `Equals` and `Normalize` in the same test. You already have tests that test your `Normalize` method. Have one that tests your `Equals` method *and* one that would test that your `Equals` uses `Normalize`!

Now, you don't test the cases where `Equals` returns `false`. If I read only your tests, I could believe that:

```
new Fraction(1,10).Equals(new Fraction(2,10)) == true
```

Because you didn't test this. The theory implies that you should test valid cases, edge cases and invalid cases!

```
[Test]
public void ComparisonTest()
{
    Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(1, 2)), Is.EqualTo(0));
    Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(9, 4)), Is.EqualTo(-1));
    Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(1, 5)), Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Here's a cool trick. The use of `[TestCase]`.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(1,2,0)]
[TestCase(9,4,-1)]
[TestCase(1,5,1)]
public void ComparisonTest(int nominator, int denominator, comparisonResult)
{
    Assert.That(new Fraction(5, 10).CompareTo(new Fraction(nominator, denominator)), Is.EqualTo(comparisonResult));
}
```

Cool right? Remember, a test *should* have *only* **one** `Assert`. Otherwise, either your code is bad (which isn't the case here) or your test is poorly written (which is the case here).

Last thing, you noticed how I used `expected` and `actual` in my tests? You should do the same thing!

Here's an example:

```
[Test]
public void AdditionTestWithSameDenominators()
{
    var expected = new Fraction(8, 5);
    var actual = new Fraction(1,5).Add(new Fraction(7,5));
    Assert.That(expected, Is.EqualTo(actual));
}
```

Ok, real last thing. That syntax : `Assert.That(...)` is weird, I feel.

Why don't you use `Assert.AreEqual`? I think it's much clearer what happens with this!

Comment: Thanks! To me it looks like I can't just compare 24/36 to 2/3 using `Equals` if I want to test normalization, because `Equals` uses `Normilze` internally. Or can I?

Comment: I like `Assert.That`, because it speaks to me in almost human language: `Assert that expected is equal to actual`. :) For simple cases I should probably use `AreEqual` though.

Comment: @Nikita Brizhak I don't understand your question :p

Comment: what I am saying is that both `Assert.That(new Fraction(24, 36).Normalize(), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(2, 3)));` and `Assert.That(new Fraction(24, 36), Is.EqualTo(new Fraction(2, 3)));` will pass due to how `Equals` is implemented. So it does not metter, if I call `Normalize` method or not, it might as well do nothing, the test will pass either way. That is why I thought it would be wrong to use  `Fraction.Equals` to validate normalization logic.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak Ooohh okay I think I get it. I've not been clear enough, you should check my edit!

Answer (score 11):

- I recommend to normalize fractions in the constructor. Otherwise you have a problem with numerator and denominator grow unnecessarily large.
- `bool less()` is usually required. BTW, given `less()`, you may infer all other comparisons in a very mechanical way.

  EDIT: Given a '<' relation, you may implement

  `a > b`  as `return b < a;`

  `a == b` as `return !(a < b) && !(b < a);`

  etc, regardless of the underlying type of arguments, as long as they form a strict weak order.
- I recommend to have an unsigned denominator.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on your second point? I don't follow :)

Answer (score 7):

I find the `Fraction` should be a `struct`. This would allow you to get rid of all those ugly `!= null` checks.

Then, I would create a new `MathHelper` class and put two functions there that have wider usage then only for a fraction:

```
public static class MathHelper
{
    public static int GreatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
    {
        var mod = a % b;
        while (mod != 0)
        {
            a = b;
            b = mod;
            mod = a % b;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static int LeastCommonMultiple(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b) / GreatestCommonDivisor(a, b);
    }
}
```

---

- As others already sugested I would use *real* operators instead of methods... but just for everything `=, !=, <, >, +, -, /, *`.
- I wouldn't reduce the fraction in the constructor, it might not be always desired, but instead add a method that returns a new, `Reduce`d fraction, with two other *utility* methods like `Negate` and `Reciprocal`, all returning new fractions.
- You're cheating in your `CompareTo` method ;-) because instead of comparing fractions like one would do you convert them to `double`s instead.
- The new `LeastCommonMultiple` you can use to add fractions so that you have smaller divisors.
- By adding `<, >` operators you can get rid fo the `IEquatable` interface.

This will also simplify your tests that then could look more *natural* like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(new Fraction(1, 3) + new Fraction(2, 3) == new Fraction(1, 1));
Assert.IsTrue(new Fraction(1, 2) + new Fraction(1, 3) == new Fraction(5, 6));
Assert.IsTrue(new Fraction(1, 3) < new Fraction(2, 3));
Assert.IsTrue(new Fraction(1, 3) < new Fraction(2, 4));
Assert.IsTrue(new Fraction(3, 3) == new Fraction(2, 2));
```

---

```
public struct Fraction : IComparable<Fraction>
{
    public bool Equals(Fraction other)
    {
        return Numerator == other.Numerator && Denominator == other.Denominator;
    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        if (denominator == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(denominator), "Denominator must not be 0");
        }

        Numerator = numerator;
        Denominator = denominator;
    }

    public int Numerator { get; }

    public int Denominator { get; }

    public Fraction Reduce()
    {
        var commonDivisor = MathHelper.GreatestCommonDivisor(Math.Abs(Numerator), Math.Abs(Denominator));
        return new Fraction(Numerator / commonDivisor, Denominator / commonDivisor);
    }

    public Fraction Negate()
    {
        return new Fraction(-Numerator, Denominator);
    }

    public Fraction Reciprocal()
    {
        return new Fraction(Denominator, Numerator);
    }

    public static Fraction operator +(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        if (f1.Denominator == f2.Denominator)
        {
            return new Fraction(f1.Numerator + f2.Numerator, f1.Denominator);
        }

        var commonDenominator = MathHelper.LeastCommonMultiple(f1.Denominator, f2.Denominator);
        var result = new Fraction(f1.Numerator * f2.Denominator + f2.Numerator * f1.Denominator, commonDenominator);

        return result;
    }

    public static Fraction operator -(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        return f1.Negate() + f2;
    }

    public static Fraction operator *(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        return new Fraction(f1.Numerator * f2.Numerator, f1.Denominator * f2.Denominator);
    }

    public static Fraction operator /(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        if (f2.Numerator == 0)
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException();
        }
        return f1 * f2.Reciprocal();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        var f1r = f1.Reduce();
        var f2r = f2.Reduce();
        return f1r.Numerator == f2r.Numerator && f1r.Denominator == f2r.Denominator;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        return !(f1 == f2);
    }

    public static bool operator <(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        return f1.Reduce().CompareTo(f2.Reduce()) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
    {
        return f1.Reduce().CompareTo(f2.Reduce()) > 0;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Fraction other)
    {
        var result = (Numerator * other.Denominator).CompareTo(other.Numerator * Denominator);
        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Numerator}/{Denominator}";
    }

    #region autogenerated 

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is Fraction && Equals((Fraction)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Numerator * 397) ^ Denominator;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of what I would have said has already been covered, but on that note, I agree with your comment TopinFrassi regarding normalization (specifically, I would leave it as written versus using equal, although I would suggest that if there's a clean way to do it in C# (something like assert(fraction.Numerator == 2 && fraction.Denumerator == 3), breaking up all tests so each has exactly one assert wouldn't be a bad thing.)  At any rate, my main suggestions would be cover some of the corner/bad-news cases:

1. Add or subtract fractions produces zero.
2. Normalizing a fraction that is 0/N produces 0/1 (which I'm pretty sure your code does do, but as a user, it would give me a warm fuzzy that you checked for that)
3. Normalizing a fraction that is 0/-N still produces 0/1 (which I again *think* your code does, but I get nervous about % and negative numbers)
4. Normalizing a fraction with -A/-B
5. I would prefer you follow something like the suggestion to use structs (or another non-nullable mechanism), but if you're going to have code that checks for null, you should verify this in tests (if for no other reason than if you're using a tool that does test code coverage, this gets you close to 100% coverage)
6. On the topic of coverage, you may want to have at least a minimal test for toString and toDouble